# Can I set a TTL for a mongoDB user?

Tags: mongodb

Just wondering if it's possible to set a TTL in system.users data in MongoDB 3.4+. 
We need to implement a routine who removes users after defined date but the TTL idea sounds better.

In the moment I don't have any environment to test it.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried this on MongoDB 4.0 and it worked!  Be careful!  You don't want to delete your root user.  To protect myself I created a TTL index on a non-existing field.  Then I added my user, then updated my user by setting this extra field.  This way my root user does not have this field and will never be auto deleted by the TTL index.

**Login as root user:**

```
use admin
db.auth("rootuser", "mypassword")
```

**Create the index:**

```
db.system.users.createIndex({ "expirationCreateDate": 1}, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 })
```

**Create a new user:**

```
db.createUser({user: "johndoe", pwd: "mysecret", roles: [{role: "root", db: "admin"}]})
```

**Update user's TTL field:**

```
db.system.users.update({_id: "admin.johndoe"}, {$set: {expirationCreateDate: new Date()}})
```

**Authenticate as new user:**

```
db.auth("johndoe", "mysecret")
```

**Run admin command:**

```
db.serverStatus()
```

If you repeat this command eventually you will receive an error:

```
> db.serverStatus()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "command serverStatus requires authentication",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

**Notes:**

You may want to consider creating the index in the background to avoid locks.  Also, it's worth noting, my example shows an expire time of 10 seconds, but I believe the thread that processes TTL expirations runs every 60 seconds, so there may be a delay.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for test it @barrypicker! In my scenario, the users will get about six months of expiration date.  It's good to know that it works!